Render JSX or an Icon inside the Monaco Editor Area in React
I'm working on a platform to showcase code snippets in form of posts. Inside a snippet, i want the creator to be able to add line-by-line explanations of the code snippets he uploads. The explanations will be shown through a tooltip or modal which will be triggered upon clicking an icon, that will be shown at the right end of a particular line, how can i render an icon inside the monaco editor with react? i've read the documentaion but can't seem to find something useful
this is my initial functioning code, nothing special.
"use client";
// import { languages } from "@/config/languages";
import { Editor, loader } from "@monaco-editor/react";
import { githubDarkTheme } from "@/config/themes/github-dark";
import { useEffect } from "react";

export default function CodeEditor({
  language,
  theme,
  fontSize,
}: {
  language: string;
  theme: string;
  fontSize: number;
}) {
  useEffect(() => {
    loader.init().then((monaco) => {
      monaco.editor.defineTheme("github-dark", githubDarkTheme as any);
      // monaco.editor.crea
    });
  }, []);
  return (
    <>
      <Editor
        height="30vh"
        theme={theme}
        defaultLanguage={language}
        defaultValue="// start writing code here ..."
        options={{
          fontFamily: "Fira Code, monospace",
          fontLigatures: true,
          fontSize: fontSize,
          padding: { top: 15 },
          // language,
        }}
        onMount={(editor, monaco) => {
          console.log("onMount", editor, monaco);
          // editor.dec
        }}
      />
    </>
  );

Searched whole docs & internet but found nothing :(

To render an icon inside the Monaco Editor area in React, you can use the dom module provided by Monaco Editor. Here's a basic example of how you can achieve this:
import { useEffect, useRef } from "react";
import { Editor, loader } from "@monaco-editor/react";
import { githubDarkTheme } from "@/config/themes/github-dark";

export default function CodeEditor({
  language,
  theme,
  fontSize,
}: {
  language: string;
  theme: string;
  fontSize: number;
}) {
  const editorRef = useRef<any>(null);

  useEffect(() => {
    loader.init().then((monaco) => {
      monaco.editor.defineTheme("github-dark", githubDarkTheme as any);
    });
  }, []);

  useEffect(() => {
    if (editorRef.current) {
      const editor = editorRef.current!._editor;
      const lineNumber = 1; // Line number where you want to show the icon

      const model = editor.getModel();
      const decoration = {
        range: model!.getFullModelRange(),
        options: {
          isWholeLine: true,
          glyphMarginClassName: "myGlyphMarginClass",
        },
      };

      editor.deltaDecorations([], [decoration]);

      const disposable = editor.onMouseDown((e) => {
        const target = e.target;
        if (target.position?.lineNumber === lineNumber) {
          // Logic to show your tooltip/modal
          console.log("Clicked line:", lineNumber);
        }
      });

      return () => {
        disposable.dispose();
      };
    }
  }, [editorRef]);

  return (
    <>
      <Editor
        height="30vh"
        theme={theme}
        defaultLanguage={language}
        defaultValue="// start writing code here ..."
        options={{
          fontFamily: "Fira Code, monospace",
          fontLigatures: true,
          fontSize: fontSize,
          padding: { top: 15 },
        }}
        onMount={(editor, monaco) => {
          editorRef.current = editor;
        }}
      />
    </>
  );
}

In this example, we're using the deltaDecorations method to add a decoration (glyph margin) to a specific line number in the editor. Then, we're using the onMouseDown event to detect clicks on the glyph margin and trigger the display of your tooltip/modal.
You can customize the lineNumber variable to specify the line where you want to show the icon. Also, make sure to add the necessary logic to show your tooltip/modal inside the onMouseDown event handler.
